# How to remove radio from quick settings in Asus zenfone 4

Tags: settings

When i bought my phone it had only 4 icons highlighted in green and some others which could be removed in and were highlighted in blue but suddenly the radio icon appeared and i am not able to remove it and I haven't even update any thing plz help

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Open the toggles bar and on the top along with the settings button there will be an icon of pencil and a page tap that and quick settings menu will launch there will be two headings scroll down the first one and uncheck fm radio and select any thing else you want to[image: the icon on the toggles bar that I'm taking about]